# How to flatten the entire package hierarchy?

Tags: java, package, hierarchy, flatten

If I want to flatten all my package hierarchy, how can I proceed and what are the gotchas?

*Note that this question is not about why I want to do this, but how.  Valid reasons, for example, would include (but would not be limited to) several of the reasons that make Proguard a useful program.*

At first I'd like to keep the class names intact but remove all the hierarchy.

So:

- *com.acme.example.SomeClass* should become either "SomeClass" or
  "a.SomeClass"
- *com.acme.sample.AnotherClass* should become either
  "AnotherClass" or "a.AnotherClass"

I did a quick check and out of about a thousand classes there aren't two with duplicate names:

```
find . -iname "*java" | sed 's/.*\///g' | sort | wc -l
```

and:

```
find . -iname "*java" | sed 's/.*\///g' | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

both give the same number of *.java* files (so I'm pretty sure there aren't any "duplicate names" in the *.java files).

I was thinking about writing a shell script that would:

- remove (or modify) the package line
- remove every "import com.acme...." line

Would this work?

What could be the things preventing this from working?  What would happen from a public/protected/default/private visibility point of view?

I guess reflection would break havoc here but thankfully we're not doing any.

Note that I only want to do that on my own classes: I don't want to modify external APIs / jars.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [proguard](http://Proguard.sourceforge.net). It's a code obfuscator with a bunch of options including flattening packages and not obfuscating other things if you don't want to.

Comment: I mentioned Proguard in my question, so I know it ; )   However I didn't know it was able to flatten the package hierarchy.  That's because Proguard's terminology is apparently a bit weird: it calls "flattening" was is simply "shortening" and the real "flattening" into a single package is called "repackaging" : )   I didn't know about this option, I'm going to try it out!

Comment: Sorry, I read over your question too quickly. In proguard 4.8 (maybe earlier versions too) there is a `-flattenpackagehierarchy` option which seems to do what you want.